# Fixing the error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_group

Tags: django, testing

I'm trying to run some simple tests with command: python manage.py test

When I do it, I get the error saying

> File "/Users/petka/.local/share/virtualenvs/movie_platform-wu_Kht1X/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 394, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_group

Anyone knows how to fix this?

movies_app/tests.py

```
    from django.test import TestCase

    class SmokeTest(TestCase):

    def test_bad_maths(self):
        self.assertEqual(1 + 1, 3)
```

Comment: Have you found a fix? I have the exact same error, but auth_group is no where in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried deleting my db.sqlite3, migrations & pycache folder then running makemigrations, syncdb...etc as several posts suggest, but it threw the exact same error, `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_group`.

Here's what worked for me: Comment out everything in urls.py and admin.py, the run makemigrations & migrate.

Details:
Commenting out urls.py then running makemigrations threw the same error, but in the traceback it pointed to a line of code in admin.py that was trying to access or create a new instance in the db. I then commented out everything in admin.py and re-ran `./manage.py makemigrations` & `./manage.py migrate` in pipenv and it worked! The migrations folder was present when I did this (pulled it from git after deleting it in other attempts to solve the problem), so I'm guessing there's no need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

have you migrated?
if not then run the following commands

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to execute the migration in the database that is used for tests. For some reason, you need to have it updated, even if it recreates everything.